# how to get a list from database without pojo class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

need to get the list of data in MySQL workbench & store the list of data in Arraylist without creating POJO/Model class in spring boot.

Comment: If you are not going to create a POJO and load the data from database, what is the point? Why load data that is not going to be used?

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo  I just want to use the list of data from the database to check the condition match or not matches. there is no need to create a separate POJO class for that

Comment: What kind of condition? Can you do the check in a query instead of loading data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***jdbctemplate.queryForList*** which will return a **List<Map<String,Object>>** where key will be column name and value will be the column value.